# What % of Python questions have the word "pythonic" in them?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

It seems like every other Python question nowadays asks if some code they wrote is "pythonic" or how to make some code more "pythonic".

This especially amuses me when the code in question is something like:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
print max(a)
# How do I make this more pythonic?
```

I'm curious, what percentage of python tagged questions have the word "pythonic" in the body or title of the post?

Comment: The irony is, to many, Pythonic neither means more efficient nor more readable. It often means *give me the one-liner*.

Comment: This might be an amusing topic for the Python chat room, but this isn't really a great fit for Meta.

Comment: Why not write your own enquiry to https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries

Comment: import parseltongue

Comment: So who deleted [pythonic]?? [Was the tag \[pythonic\] summarily deleted without discussion?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367855/was-the-tag-pythonic-summarily-deleted-without-discussion)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thankfully we have good old [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/850293). No Python has been near the production of this answer:

```sql
select cnt [all python]
     , title
     , body
     , cast(title as decimal) / cnt * 100 as [% title]
     , cast(body as decimal) / cnt  * 100 as [% body]
     , (cast(body as decimal) + cast(title as decimal))  / cnt  * 100 as tot
from 
(
select count(*) as cnt
     , sum(
       case 
       when title like '%pythonic%' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_ai 
       then 1
       else 0
       end
       ) title
     , sum(
       case 
       when body like '%pythonic%' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_ai 
       then 1
       else 0
       end
       ) body
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where p.posttypeid = 1
and t.tagname ='python'
) data
```

Which renders for today:

> ```
> all python title body % title     % body      tot
> ```

```
---------- ----- ---- ----------- ----------- ----------- 
946761      2213  9470 0.233744313 1.000252439 1.233996753
```

Don't forget that SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday.

For better self-service follow the [awesome tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).

Comment: Or one can divide [this number](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aq+%22pythonic%22) by [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aq): 9,746/949,847 = 1.026%