# Was the tag [pythonic] summarily deleted without discussion?

Tags: discussion, tags

EDIT: I mistakenly thought [pythonic] had been a distinct tag in its own right (not a synonym to [python]) and had been deleted in 2018.

Where is the audit trail of what happened, and why was there no discussion?

While we're at it, what is/was the case for or against [pythonic]?

- the generic tag [idiomatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idiomatic) exists
- it was [overused](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367687/what-of-python-questions-have-the-word-pythonic-in-them), especially in the sense *"what is a one-liner for ...?"*, sometimes "Givemetehcodez". (That sounds like an argument for giving extra scrutiny to such questions, but not for removing the tag)

Comment: [pythonic] seems to be made a synonym of python tag. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/synonyms)

Comment: @SurajRao: seems to have happened around or since the question referenced above (May 10)

Comment: @smci umm.... it was originally created nearly 6 years ago... Whether it took ~6 years to get approved is another thing. However, the rename count of 125 seems to be about right for how often I'd imagine 6 years of it being used would be...

Comment: Also the linked question is not about the tag but to me it looks like the keyword "pythonic" in question body

Comment: Discussions about it raged at MSE in 2013, find them by googling site:meta.stackexchange.com pythonic.  Not so sure what the conclusion was, other than it belonging in the [coding-style] meta tag category.  But surely enough to get sufficient users to vote for the synonym.

Comment: yes cross site dupe https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140325/is-it-right-that-pythonic-is-synonymized-to-python

Comment: @JonClements: but it's not a synonym for 'Python'. It is a one-word term meaning 'idiomatic Python'. I don't understand your comments. I couldn't find any discussion or approval for removing it as a tag in its own right. (EDIT: SurajRao found a 2012 discussion.)

Comment: Okay... I'm just pointing out that "happened recently" isn't the case... the syn' was first proposed in 2012 and from @SurajRao's link (kudos Hans) - looks like it's not been a thing for over 5 years and no one's missed it as a tag...

Comment: Ah ok. It got made a synonym back in 2012. Thanks @SurajRao for that 2012 link. I was unaware of that. I miss it as a tag, but if most others don't, I can live without it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No one deleted the tag (I understand you are referring to burnination).

[pythonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pythonic) was created as a synonym of [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). See [python synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/synonyms).

As @JonClements pointed out it was created 6 years ago [Jul 5,2012]. Relevant MSE discussion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140325/is-it-right-that-pythonic-is-synonymized-to-python).

Also, the linked question you are referring to relates to the usage of the word "pythonic" in the question body and not the tag itself.

Comment: Thanks. Re *" the linked question you are referring to relates to the usage of the word "pythonic" in the question body and not the tag itself."* I know that, and I never said it wasn't. I mistakenly thought that [pythonic] had only recently disappeared, and that article was merely the only thing I found on Meta that seemed to shed any light on what might have happened and when.